# ModX: Use PHP var in Wayfinder?

Tags: php, variables, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I have a snippet which gets document IDs from the DB.

I want to out put these in a menu with Wayfinder but am having trouble getting it to work. Does anyone know the correct way of placing a PHP var within Wayfinder? Tried this but no luck:

```
echo '[[Wayfinder? &includeDocs=`' . $docid . '`]]';
```

(PS: using Revo)

EDIT: Added more code

In a nut shell, my code gets a logged in users id from sessions and finds thier access group. Ultimate goal is to display links to resources that are within their access group. This is the later part of the snippet where I have got the appropriate resource IDs and just need to out put them.

```
//RETRIEVE DOCUMENT GROUPS RELATED TO ACCESS GROUPS
          $docgroups = "SELECT * FROM `modx_document_groups` WHERE `document_group` = '$target' ";

          $docstmt = $modx->query($docgroups );              

          while ($docrow = $docstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $docid = $docrow['document'];            

          echo '[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &includeDocs=`' . $docid . '`]]';

          }//END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modx, your snippets must return a value to access it in chunks/templates etc. This is one way:

```
//MySnippet
<?php
// logic
$docIDs = array(1, 2, 23, 17);
return implode(',', $docIDs);
```

and then your wayfinder call uses the snippet:

```
 // wayfinder call
[[!Wayfinder? &includeDocs=`[[!MySnippet]]`]]

// is the same as:
[[!Wayfinder? &includeDocs=`1,2,23,17`]]
```

Comment: Ah ok so 'return' is the output of my snippet? Then theres no way to incorporate Wayfinder in a while loop? I would just have to out put an array?

Comment: why would you want to use WF in a while loop? - perhaps post your snippet code might help clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: Ive added more code above. I'm sure Wayfinder in the loop is not necessary and that your way is better anyway

Comment: your way would make multiple calls to wayfinder and create multiple lists, unnecessary processing etc. But I can see your logic! By simply creating an array in the `while` loop, and passing the return value to wayfinder you have much more control and should ultimately do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this at Modx Revolution :

```
$c = $modx->newQuery('modResourceGroupResource');
$c->where(array( 'document_group' => $target ));
$docs = $modx->getCollection('modResourceGroupResource', $c);

$docids = array();
foreach($docs as $doc) {
    $docids[] = $doc->get('document');
}

$output = $modx->runSnippet('Wayfinder',array(
    'startId' => 0,
    'includeDocs' => implode(',', $docids);
));

return $output;
```

Comment: Yep, this is the right way and much more efficient as it only needs to be parsed once.